# Couple of questions on the confusing "shutdown" Linux command

Tags: linux, shutdown

http://man.he.net/?topic=shutdown&section=all

1. So, am I to understand that you MUST specify the "time into the future" as minutes? Seconds are not possible?

   ```
   shutdown +1
   ```

   This is both the default and the lowest possible (except for +0)? In other words, 60 seconds minimum? I cannot specify that it is to shutdown/reboot in ten seconds?
2. If I do `shutdown now` or `shutdown +0`, does that mean that it "aggressively" just cuts off anything that is running, giving them no signal or chance to exit cleanly? Instant force restart?
3. Let's say I use one minute (or more). What if something still has not exited cleanly when the time is over? Will it force-reboot/restart anyway then, no matter what state any running application is in?

Comment: There is not _one_ "the" `shutdown` command.  Linux itself does not have one at all, and _Linux-based_ operating systems have several, from the one for van Smoorenburg `init`+`rc`, through Upstart's, and systemd's (whose manual you are reading), to [one that I wrote](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/shutdown.xml).  [Even runit has its own](https://manpages.debian.org/sid/runit-init/shutdown.8.en.html).  There is broad agreement on a subset of command-line usage, but it is _not_ a universal; especially in the case of runit's `shutdown`.

Answer (score 2):

The time is the time to start the shutdown, not the time to completion. Therefore shutdown now will start shutting down now. It will complete the full procedure that shutdown in one minute does.

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct according to `man 8 shutdown`

> This is both the default and the lowest possible (except for +0)? In other words, 60 seconds minimum? I cannot specify that it is to shutdown/reboot in ten seconds?

Either you specify `now` or at least a minute into the future.

Alternatively you can run, e.g.

`sleep 10 && poweroff`

2. No, the system will go through all the shutdown steps normally (stopping user processes, stopping services, flushing caches, unmounting devices and rebooting/powering off).
3. Yes, it will force halt/reboot/power off but it depends on how a service/application was started. See, for instance `DefaultTimeoutStopSec` : https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html

Comment: You have misread (3).

Comment: @JdeBP I'm not sure about that. *What if something still has not exited cleanly when the time is over? Will it force-reboot/restart anyway then, no matter what state any running application is in?* Yes, it will force restart/reboot regardless of the application state.

Comment: You've not taken into account the first sentence and the connection to (1) and (2).